# DriveActivity API returning function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive, google-drive-activity-api

I'm trying to get the activity on a Shared Drive in G-Suite using Apps Scripts.

I can call the API using the below code:

```
function test () {
  var param = {
    "ancestorName": "items/0AEx8HmJfSvziUk9PVA",
    "pageSize": 10, 
    "consolidation_strategy": { "legacy": {} }
  }
  
  var response = DriveActivity.Activity.query(param)
  var activities = response.activities; 
  
  for(var i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
    var activity = activities[i]; 
    console.log(activity.primaryActionDetail); 
  }
}
```

What I'm expecting is what's displayed here in the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/actiondetail#ActionDetail),

```
activity[i]: 

        {
        edit{}
        } 

activity[i]: 
{comment:{post}}
```

but instead I get what looks like functions:

```
"{ getCreate: [Function],
  getComment: [Function],
  setRestore: [Function],
  getSettingsChange: [Function],
  getRestore: [Function],
  setDelete: [Function],
  setReference: [Function],
  setRename: [Function],
  getEdit: [Function],
  setMove: [Function],
  setEdit: [Function],
  setSettingsChange: [Function],
  setPermissionChange: [Function],
  getRename: [Function],
  setCreate: [Function],
  getMove: [Function],
  setComment: [Function],
  edit: { toString: [Function] },
  toString: [Function],
  getReference: [Function],
  getDlpChange: [Function],
  getPermissionChange: [Function],
  setDlpChange: [Function],
  getDelete: [Function] }"
```

Not sure what to do at this point, been trying to figure this out for longer than I care to mention.

Comment: In your situation, when `console.log(JSON.stringify(activity.primaryActionDetail))` is used instead of `console.log(activity.primaryActionDetail)`, will that be the result you expect?

Comment: Actually, yes! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users how have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this was using JSON.stringify(response), which brought back the response as a string, and not the evaluated response.